# R -- Error in adding(2, 3) : could not find function "adding"

Tags: r, rstudio, user-defined-functions

I have defined a simple user defined R function called "adding", to add two numbers 2 & 3 and display the output 5. 
When I tried calling this function, I experience function not defined error.

(I searched a lot for this solution here, but most answers are based on inclusions of some packages that actually fixes the problem. But I don't need any package here for used defined function)

```
adding <- function(a,b)
{
  sum <- a + b
  return (sum)
}

mainFunction <- function()
{
  print("Adding two numbers 2 and 3")
  result <- adding(2,3)
  print("The result is:")
  print(result)
}
```

I used the "Run" command in R studio to execute step-by-step starting from the first print statement of the "mainFunction".

```
Error in adding(2, 3) : could not find function "adding"
```

What mistake am I making? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is `adding` in Environment at the time when you Run?

Comment: You should select all of your codes and then hi `RUN`. I tried your code and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah. "adding" function is defined in the environment.

Comment: I selected all the code and pressed "RUN", but the console does not display my output, it simply reprints my entire program.

Comment: When you selected and ran all the code, what you are doing is assigning the functions to environment, during which all of your codes are printed. Once they are done, try `mainFunction()` in your console window

Comment: My bad! Thank you so much. It ran perfectly. I did not realize that I am suppose to source it first (select all and run). Then run the function that I need.
Thank you so much Chris and MFR.

Comment: How do I close this question as I have got my answer now?